# How can I change the image used by a TileSet in Godot?

Tags: godot

I have a tile set that uses an image.  I want it to use a new image.  The new image has a different name/path than the old image.

How do I tell the tile set to use the new image?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the Tile Sets area (see bottom bar)
2. Select the Tile Set
3. Select the "Texture" dropdown
4. Change "Resource > Path" to the new path

[image]